ffmpeg -i desktop Output file does not contain any stream
I'm trying to screen record a remote Windows VM machine which I'm accessing through ssh. I'm executing this command ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -t 00:00:10 output.mp4 which is returning the following error:
ffmpeg version 7.1-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 14.2.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --en
able-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libss
h --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lib
aom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enabl
e-libharfbuzz --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2
--enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvpl --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-libgme
--enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --en
able-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      59. 39.100 / 59. 39.100
  libavcodec     61. 19.100 / 61. 19.100
  libavformat    61.  7.100 / 61.  7.100
  libavdevice    61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
  libavfilter    10.  4.100 / 10.  4.100
  libswscale      8.  3.100 /  8.  3.100
  libswresample   5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libpostproc    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
[gdigrab @ 000001a87f3af600] Capturing whole desktop as 1024x768x32 at (0,0)
[gdigrab @ 000001a87f3af600] Failed to capture image (error 5)
[gdigrab @ 000001a87f3af600] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: bmp, none, 754987 kb/s): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, gdigrab, from 'desktop':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: 754987 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: bmp, none, 754987 kb/s, 30 fps, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
[out#0/mp4 @ 000001a87f3aeec0] Output file does not contain any stream
Error opening output file output.mp4.
Error opening output files: Invalid argument

If I take a remote desktop connection and use the same command, then it works perfectly.
I've also tried running ffmpeg.exe -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=800x600:r=30:d=60 out.mp4 which records something but it's just a black screen.
Does anyone have any idea what could be happening? I'm clueless at this point as I haven't been able to find more info online.

FFmpeg fails to capture the desktop, because the SSH connection doesn't have access to the user's desktop.
As a workaround, we may execute the grabbing command from a Scheduled Task.
The following example, assumes that ffmpeg.exe is located in c:\Tmp\FFmpeg, and that we are saving the MP4 file to c:\Tmp\FFmpeg folder.


Create a file named CaptureDesktop.ps1 in c:\Tmp\FFmpeg with the following content:
 cd c:\Tmp\FFmpeg
 .\ffmpeg.exe -y -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -t 00:00:10 c:\Tmp\FFmpeg\output.mp4 -report


Create a new Scheduled Task named CaptureDesktop:
Run taskschd.msc for opening the Task Scheduler (opening the Task Scheduler may require remote desktop connection).

Go to Action -> Create Task
Name the task: CaptureDesktop
Go to the Action tab, and press "New".
Set the program to: powershell.exe.
Set the arguments to: -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy bypass -File c:\Tmp\FFmpeg\CaptureDesktop.ps1


For executing the task (capturing the desktop) execute from SSH command line:
schtasks /run /tn "CaptureDesktop"



Here are few screenshots (from Windows 7):
Creating a new Scheduled Task:

Adding an action:


Example for captured desktop (sample frame from output.mp4):


Note:
The -report argument to FFmpeg, is used for creating a report file - in case of an error, we may view the latest log file (stored in c:\Tmp\FFmpeg).
